# Equation referencing in Chapter, Section & Sub-sections

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

When I label my equations, I'd like there to be an indication of the chapter / section / sub-section they are contained in.

At the moment, when I reference a label in say Chapter 3 Section 2 Sub-Section 2, it comes up as (3.15) where I'd like (3.2.2.1) or something of that form.

Just wondering if this is possible - thanks.

Comment: Please, always add a `Minimal Working Example` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesubsection.\arabic{equation}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{One}
\section{Two}
\subsection{one}
\begin{equation}\label{eq0}
a = b
\end{equation}
\subsection{two}
\subsection{three}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
a = b
\end{equation}

Equation (\ref{eq0}).

Equation (\ref{eq1}).


\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot

Comment: @jramponi The right way to say thanks here is to approve the anwer.